# Derivative of a convex function vs. Derivative of a linear function

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, derivatives, convex-analysis

I have one question regarding the derivative of a convex function. Let's say we have two functions (one convex, one linear) with the inequality sign as follows:

$
s^{1-k} > \frac{1-(1-p)s}{p}, \forall s \in (0, 1), p \in (0, 1)
$
If this is OK to say, then what is the reason behind this?

Thanks you!

Comment: Please don't edit out your question after someone posts an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(s)=s^{1-k}-\frac {1-(1-p)s} p$. Suppose $k \leq \frac 1 p$. Then $f'(s)=(1-k)s^{-k}+\frac {1-p} p$. For $s$ near $1$ we can see that $f'(s) >0$ (because $p<1$).  Hence $f$ is increasing in $(1-\delta ,1)$ for some $\delta >0$.  Since $f(1-)=0$ it follows that $f(s) <0$ in $(1-\delta ,1)$ but this contradicts the given inequality. Hence we must have $k >\frac 1 p$.